# React-Navigation: Is the performance optimization with react-native-screens also available for TabNavigation?

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I was exited to hear about the possibility to use [native navigation in React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/react-native-screens).
In the [respective blog post](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2020/02/06/react-navigation-5.0#native-stack-navigator) however, it only speaks of native Stack-Navigations. We are using a bottomTabNavigation, so I wonder if the use of react-native-screens is also useful when using tab navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's used in bottom tabs to improve memory usage by detaching unfocused screens. But the tab bar itself is made in JS.

Since the bottom tab navigator doesn't implement any animations or gestures, native implementation is not necessary to achieve good performance.

Comment: Right, I don't mean animations either. Without react-native-screens, the whole react-native app plays in a single native view. But React-native-screens allows you to switch between native views. So my question is whether this possibility also works with tab navigation, i.e. an app with 4 tabs would have 4 native views instead of just one. If I understand your answer correctly, this is possible.

Comment: Yeah, like I said react native screens is used in bottom tabs